# Maven using external directory as config dir

Tags: java, maven

I'm using maven to generate a jar with all dependencies inside the jar (as shown in 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) question). This is working fine. The problem is, I need to have some .properties file un an external directory (like C:/program/config) where there will be some configurations parameters. These parameters are used in Spring:

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
```

How can I add this directory to the classpath so that Spring (or the java code whenever it neets to) can access to the files under C:/program/config.

Note that I don't wan't to include the files inside the jar, I wan't that the classpath recognize this directory (I know I can do it in a cmd with set CLASSPATH="", but I neet to avoid this).

Thanks.

Comment: My advice: Don't do it. Builds are meant to be reproducible on other computers (like the build server). Your approach breaks that. No matter what problem you are trying to solve, there is probably a much better and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the spring.xml like.Put database properties in resource floder

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>${DRIVER}</value>
        </property>
```

Comment: I know this works, the problem is that "database.properties" is stored in "C:/program/config", and those files are not in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the simplest solution will be to include explictly `c:\program\config` into the classpath, but if you want to avoid it, I just think of another alternative: You need to include the files `c:\program\config\*.properties` into **a new Maven library**, and then set it as a **system dependency** of your code:

```
- myproject
  /pom.xml -> has a dependency on my_config_files
  /src/java/main -> source code

- my_config_files
  /pom.xml -> includes c:\program\config as a resource directory
```

In this way, you'll end up with two libraries: One for the code, and the other just for configuration files.